# Twitter bootsrap button text is white on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I am using standard Google Chrome for MacOS. Version 17.0.963.46. For some reason, whenever I go to any Twitter Bootstrap site, the button text is white. I have included a picture of one instance of this, but it appears to be universal and across different versions of Twitter Bootstrap.

This is not an issue in Firefox.

[image]

Does anybody know if this is a known bug? If so, is there a known fix for this? I have googled, but have not found anything relevant.

Specifically, I am looking for a fix to Twitter Bootstrap so that this will not be a problem for my own site.

Note, this is how the style is computed in Chrome:

```
.btn - #333
.btn - #333
.btn - rgb(255, 255, 255) user stylesheet
a - #0069d6
a:-webkit-any-link - -webkit-link user agent stylesheet
.alert-message.block-message.error, .alert-message.block-message.success, .alert-message.block-message.info - #404040
.btn.danger, .alert-message.danger, .btn.danger:hover, .alert-message.danger:hover, .btn.error, .alert-message.error, .btn.error:hover, .alert-message.error:hover, .btn.success, .alert-message.success, .btn.success:hover, .alert-message.success:hover, .btn.info, .alert-message.info, .btn.info:hover, .alert-message.info:hover - #ffffff
.alert-message - #404040
body - #808080
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you access it here? http://postimage.org/image/6b7i5lbl1/

Comment: Yes, now I see it. I haven't seen this issue myself on any bootstrapped sites. Weird. What page were you on when you took that screenshot?

Comment: This page: http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/195_bootstrap/demo/main.html#

Comment: I noticed that Chrome defines the white button as a "user stylesheet", which is strange since I don't have any user stylesheets defined.

Comment: It's the same thing even on the official site: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: switching to chrome release channel just to test this :P

Comment: Thanks. I actually just tried removing my Chrom preferences and that seems to have fixed it. I'm not sure what it is specifically, but I was previously using a Chrome developers release, so maybe something is mangled in the preferences that's causing this. Thanks for checking into it. I'm pretty sure the problem is a Chrome preference. I hope this helps anybody else who finds this.

Comment: I'm now on Chrome 17.0.963.46/OSX. I'm not seeing the issue. Edit: Saw you fixed it. Glad it's working now! :)

Comment: Got it. It was an extension called "Redmine Extended1.4"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out there is a google Chrome Extension called "Redmine Extended 1.4" which causes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, here is how i fixed it:

Basically, must edit the redmine.js and style.css files in: Default/Extensions/mkpkclfhemlehfbeinbjnbjebbikgfpb/1.4_0/ (under the Chrome or Chromium folder)

And replace the css clases used in the extensions from 'btn' to 'redmine_btn', to avoid the problem that the extension was overriding bootstrap system-wide.

Credits:

"Andrzej WineckiJul" posted this fix in the extension comments.

Original post in : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redmine-extended/mkpkclfhemlehfbeinbjnbjebbikgfpb/reviews